# How to texturing a plane with the cloud image in ARcore_flutter_plugin

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, aranchor

i want to texture my detected AR plane with image rendered from firestore.
i can add multiple images on plane horizontally with ontappointandplane method , but unable to texture image to plane with on detectedplane methods

```
Future _handleOnPlaneDetected(List<ArCoreHitTestResult> hits) async {
    for (var hit in hits) {
      await _addImage(hit);
    }
  }

  Future _addImage(ArCoreHitTestResult hit) async {
    final bytes =
    (await rootBundle.load('assets/earth.jpg')).buffer.asUint8List();

    final earth = ArCoreNode(
      image: ArCoreImage(bytes: bytes, width: 500, height: 500),
      position: hit.pose.translation + vector.Vector3(0.0, -0.1, 0.0),
      rotation: vector.Vector4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -hit.pose.rotation[3]),
    );

    arCoreController?.addArCoreNodeWithAnchor(earth);
  }
```